# Using spread in factory function instead of class `extends`

Tags: javascript, factory-pattern

I have a replacement for `class User ...` as a factory function below:

```js
const user = (name, age) => {
    return {
        name: name,
        age: age,
    }
}
```

I have an `admin`, too, that I would normally `extend` using ES6 classes. How would I do this using spread to give `admin` the properties of `user` as well?

```js
const admin = (level) => {
    return {
       level: level,
    }
}
```

Comment: And regarding the question, what's about just `const admin = { ...user('admin', 20), level }`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Comment: `const admin = (level, user) => ({ level, ...user })`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general approach when using factory functions is one of composition. This is what takes the place of inheritance. To compose two different objects together, you could easily just [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the object props, like [Eric Elliott's functional mixin approach](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-factory-functions-with-es6-4d224591a8b1#fb43):

```js
const user = (name, age) => ({ name, age })

// The mixin approach
const withAdminLevel = (level, user) => ({ ...user, level })

console.log(withAdminLevel(1, user('John Doe', 30)))
```

From that idea, though, we could also just use the `user()` factory function from inside `admin()`, instead of passing in a user. This could simplify your calls, but may not be as desirable in some cases (Ex. when you need to "upgrade" a user):

```js
const user = (name, age) => ({ name, age })

// Use "user" factory function inside to simplify calls
const admin = (level, ...args) => ({ ...user(...args), level })

console.log(admin(1, 'John Doe', 30))
```

Finally, we can combine these two:

```js
const user = (name, age) => ({ name, age })

// The mixin approach
const withAdminLevel = (level, user) => ({ ...user, level })

// Use "user" factory function inside to simplify calls
const admin = (level, ...args) => withAdminLevel(level, user(...args))

const existingUser = user('John Doe', 30)

console.log(withAdminLevel(1, existingUser)) // upgrade
console.log(admin(2, 'Jane Doe', 28)) // still simple to do
```

Comment: thanks!  if I wanted to make a `superAdmin` that extended `withAdminLevel` using the mixin approach, would I just have one of the args be a `withAdminLevel` object?

Comment: @Michlle95 Would `superAdmin` just have a certain `level` value? Or would it also have additional props on top of a regular `admin`?

Comment: oh I see your point...how would the difference of those 2 scenarios be handled

Comment: Keep in mind that "Composition is more of a way of thinking than a particular technique in code." (quote from that Eric Elliott article). That said, here's a couple examples of how I might tackle those scenarios:
https://jsfiddle.net/x4c13zwu/
https://jsfiddle.net/x4c13zwu/1/